# Does a creature standing still inside a Prismatic Wall have to make the DEX saves on each round?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Prismatic Wall RAW says:

> (...) when a creature attempts to reach into or pass through the wall (...) as it passes or reaches through each layer, the creature must make a DEX save or be affected by that layer's properties (...)

Standing still inside the wall (it is 1 inch thick) is not an attempt to reach into or pass through. The creature indeed passed through when it entered the wall.

So, by RAW, does it have to make the DEX saves if it chooses to stay inside the wall after entering it?

Comment: Yes, I know I asked- [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103604/11402) question about the same time as this one, but even though the question relates, they are two different issues. [1 question = 1 post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what/6455#6455)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you happen to get restrained by the indigo layer, you already passed through the other layers and **do not have to repeat those saving throws**.

If you decide to stay "inside" the wall (so you are partly inside and partly outside of the 1-inch-thick wall) the same rules apply. Per rules, you already passed through the layers.

You only have to make all saving throws again, if you decide to pass through it again.

Comment: You might want to add that a creature "inside" the wall may still need to make Constitution saves against the blindness effect of the wall, which is triggered if the creature starts its turn within 20 feet of it.

Comment: A large creature can stay inside without having to move through again.

Comment: Also the wall might be diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already passed through several layers, survived, and are currently standing across several layers (1 inch is very thin after all), you do not need to make DEX saves for those layers unless you fully leave and re-enter any of them.

However, if you are standing in front of a freshly cast wall (a wall cannot be [cast on top of you](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Prismatic%20Wall#content)), you must first 
place your body exactly *in* but not *through* (and out the other end of) any one of the 7 layers. This means both you have both

- passed through the layers before this layer
- reached into this particular layer

So, you will need to perform at least 1 and at most 7 DEX saving throws. Note, even if you fail a DEX save on the Indigo layer and are Restrained, it's still very easy to accidentally touch and thus reach into the violet layer.

Comment: what is the point of the first quote?

Comment: Added a little explanation -- @Mindwin, does this work?

Comment: it doesn't. the quote happens at the casting of the spell, the question assumes the wall already exists. Of course if  the wall already exists it will need to go through the other layers. The question premises assumes it has already happened and survived. Now it has chosen to remain inside the wall. My fear is that you mixed my twinned questions and answered a hybrid of both. each one deals with a different aspect. take that in mind.

Comment: Hm, actually, I hadn't read it yet. Perhaps if I had, I might have been able to more carefully avoid answers to it. The way I read your question, I thought we were debating the technicalities of "staying inside" the wall and the creature's intent (so, "I'm not technically trying to enter and and then exit the layer, so I'm not  really 'passing through'. Do I still need to make the DEX save?") In retrospect, this is a bit of a silly question, so sorry about that!