# If you force creature into the Snare spell square does it activate?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, forced-movement

Snare is a spell that activates when

> The trap triggers when a Small creature or larger moves into the area protected by the spell.

Would forced movement via the Thornwhip cantrip snare the foe?

Comment: Related: "[Are there any rules relevant to involuntary movement and effects other than Opportunity Attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71905)" and "[Does forced movement trigger the effects of the Prismatic Wall spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157673)"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Compared to similar rulings, yes

The **Grasping Arrow** from the Arcane Archer says:

> The creature hit by the arrow [...] takes 2d6 slashing damage the
> first time on each turn it moves 1 foot or more without teleporting.

For that J. Crawford [ruled](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/12/09/does-the-arcane-archers-grasping-arrow-deal-slashing-damage-if-an-affected-creature-is-forcefully-moved/), that forced movement counts as a move.
**Booming Blade** on the other hand says the following:

> If the target willingly moves 5 feet or more [...]

Unwilling moves are here specifically excluded. Consider that on page 7 of the PHB it says:

> **Specific Beats General**

Which means the following: "Move" means every possible way of movement, willing or unwilling, by foot, air or water, except if it says something different.

Answer (score 17):

## Yes.

There are a number of spells in Fifth Edition which produce effects when a creature transits their areas of effect and this is one of them. The wording for each spell can vary a little, indicating whether or not the movement needs to be willing or not.

For example:

**Prismatic Wall**:

> When a creature attempts to reach into or pass through the wall [...]

**Wall of Fire**:

> A creature takes the same damage when it enters the wall for the first time on a turn or ends its turn there.

**Snare** says:

> The trap triggers when a Small creature or larger moves into the area protected by the spell.

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) includes a discussion on this topic in regard to a different AoE spell (*Moonbeam*):

> Entering such an area of effect needn’t be voluntary, unless a spell says otherwise. You can, therefore, hurl a creature into the area with a spell like *thunderwave*.

It is worth pointing out that they're talking about spells that have wording similar to *Moonbeam* which trigger when a creature "enters the area of effect". They don't include it on the list, but this is also how *Snare* is worded.

Sage advice summarizes it succinctly: *You’re essentially creating a hazard on the battlefield*. Snare is a magical trap, much like any trap that is built into the design of the adventuring environment.

If I push a monster onto a mundane pressure plate trap in a dungeon, I expect it to go off without consideration for whether or not the monster wanted to end up on that pressure plate.

To that end, *Snare*, once cast, becomes a trap like any other and any appropriately sized creature that ends up in the *Snare's* space, friend or foe, willing or unwilling, would trigger the trap.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, that reasoning seems pretty solid to me. "Spell is unclear, ask your DM, what I would do as DM"

Comment: @Rev Thanks! I appreciate that. I was scratching my head over the downvotes, too.

Comment: *'trigger when a creature "enters the area of effect". They don't include it on the list, but this is also how Snare is worded.'* Technically, *snare* is literally worded differently. It matters if a teleporting creature 'enters' the area of the snare, but didn't actually 'move into' it with its legs.