# Does Flame Stride activate when you are moved against your will?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, unearthed-arcana, forced-movement

The latest Unearthed Arcana includes a spell Flame Stride:

> The billowing flames of a dragon cover your feet,
> granting you explosive speed. For the duration,
> your speed increases by 20 feet and moving
> doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks.
> When you move within 5 feet of a creature or
> object that isn’t being worn or carried, it takes
> 1d6 fire damage from your trail of heat. A
> creature or object can take this damage only
> once during a turn.

The spell specifies when *you* move, so a creature approaching you would not take the damage. but what if the character was hit by a Thunderwave spell and knocked back 10 feet, would any creatures the character passes or finishes movement next too still take the flame stride damage?

Comment: Related: "[If you force creature into the Snare spell square does it activate?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181968)" and "[Are there any rules relevant to involuntary movement and effects other than Opportunity Attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71905)" and "[Does forced movement trigger the effects of the Prismatic Wall spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157673)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### If a feature requires that movement be willing, it will say so.

Consider *booming blade*:

> If the target willingly moves 5 feet or more before then, the target takes 1d8 thunder damage, and the spell ends.

Features tell you when movement must be willing movement to trigger the feature. How else are you supposed to know that it requires willing movement? Since Flame Stride does not specify that movement must be willing, it does not have to be willing.

Comment: Booming Blade is just about the only feature that actually uses the term "willing". It's often used as shorthand for "moving using your Movement, Action, or Bonus Action" as seen in Opportunity Attack rules, but you still provoke OAs if you are *forced* to run away (using your movement) - which *wouldn't* trigger BB.

Comment: Dissonant Whispers is one such spell that causes unwilling movement that consumes the creatures reaction to move. https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers For areas of effect, this would trigger the damage for them as the creature enters, but it wouldn't trigger Booming Blade.

Comment: @PaydenK.Pringle Most AoEs will also trigger on forced movement as long they say: "When a creature moves into the spell's area for the first time on a turn" or similar.

Comment: @Adeptus Is there an accurate example of implicit shorthand, because the OA rules don't support this since they had to add the paragraph: "You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction. For example, you don't provoke an opportunity attack if an explosion hurls you out of a foe's reach or if gravity causes you to fall past an enemy."

Comment: @FeyLong I meant to say, it's often *inaccurately* used as shorthand. Like I said, Booming Blade cares about "willing", OA only cares if *you* moved yourself (like you quoted). The trigger for Flame Stride would be the same as for OA - "using your movement, action, or reaction".

Comment: Why would the trigger for flame stride or Ashardalon's Stride be the same as OA? They don't have a paragraph about using your movement, action, or reaction like OA does.

Comment: @FeyLong because it says "when you *move*". Which has been defined (in OA & other places) to exclude "when you are pulled/pushed/thrown/teleported"

Comment: @Adeptus Where is it defined in OA? what are the other places it is defined at? Because they included a paragraph adding qualifiers to OA specifically doesn't mean that paragraph was providing a definition you were supposed to apply to all phrases of when you move. Just like mace of Terror adds more effects to frightened creatures, doesn't mean it's providing a definition for frightened condition.